# <td> alignment issue in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i am using the following html code:

```
<table class="question" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="99%">
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td style="width:5px;" height="10" text-align="left">hello</td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

desired output(getting in all the browsers except IE7):

```
  hello
```

in IE 7 getting the following output:

```
              hello //extra space is being added in the beginning of the text
```

my problem is the alignment of text inside the td tag in IE7. I searched in the internet but could not find any satisfactory answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Better reset it using `td{ margin:0; padding:0}`

Comment: @user1671639 thanks for the reply but its not working

Comment: Got a !DOCTYPE declaration?

Comment: I just tested on Browserstack with IE7 native and there's no gap for me.  Presumably you have this code inside a `<table>`?  Do you have any more code than this?

Comment: @davidpauljunior i updated my code,have a look

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all in IE7.  What doctype are you using? Do you have a screenshot of it happening?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so we also have your CSS?

Comment: Why are you trying to cram the text "hello" in a 5px space anyway? I'm not surprised that different browsers handle such exceptions differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had an issue with the width of td.increased to 10px and it was working fine.thanks to mr lister for ponting out the same.

<`td style="width:10px;" height="10" text-align="left">hello</td>`